# What is wrong with the following program when trying to access size of multiple files?

Tags: python

What is wrong with the following program when trying to access size of multiple files?

```
import os, glob
cwd = "C:\\temp"
files = glob.glob (cwd + "\\.jpg")
with open ("file_size.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for file in files:
        get_size = os.path.getsize (file)
        outfile.writelines (get_size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[writelines()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) is for writing iterables to a file:

> Write a sequence of strings to the file. The sequence can be any
>   iterable object producing strings, typically a list of strings.

Replace `writelines()` with `write()` and use `str(get_size)`:

```
outfile.write(str(get_size))
```

This will write each file size on a new line in a file.

Or, alternatively, collect sizes into a list, and then write via `writelines()`:

```
filesizes = [str((os.path.getsize(file)) for file in files]
with open ("file_size.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(filesizes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a number to `file.writelines()`.

```
print >>outfile, get_size
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob` uses shell expansion. `c:\temp\.jpg` would only match a file called `.jpg`. You mean

```
files = glob.glob(cwd + r'\*.jpg")
```

(note the use of the raw string prefix to avoid having to escape the backslash).